# Given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+\sin(a_n)}{2}\right)^n$ also converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$  converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+\sin(a_n)}{2}\right)^n$ converges.

I tried to prove it using the Comparison Test and the Ratio Test but I am not able to come to a conclusive result using those two. I've tried all other convergence tests available to me but I have no luck solving this question. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$, so for big $n$ we have $|a_n|<\frac{1}{2}$, so $|\frac{1+\sin a_n}{2}|\leq \frac{3}{4}$. Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $|a_n| \to 0$, so for sufficiently large $n$ you'll have $|1+\sin(a_n)|/2 < 3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea will be if $\sum a_n < \infty$ then $a_n \to 0$, which would mean $\sin a_n \to 0$ as well, since for $x \to 0$, you have $\sin x \approx x$. So for $n > N$, each term in your series can be bounded by
$$
\frac{1 + \sin(a_n)}{2} < \frac{2}{3},
$$
or any other number in $(1/2,1)$ and now your sum bounds by geometric series.